# Glyphicons shows up as a box when deployed to heroku (using amazon cloudfront to host static files) (Rails 4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I am using glyphicons via the bootstrap gem with Rails 4 and it works perfectly fine in development but when I deploy it to heroku it shows up as boxes rather than the actual icon. The pictures are given below.

[image]

[image]

The icons are suppose to be arrows but they show up as boxes. I have added the following lines in the custom.css.scss file.

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import 'bootstrap-datetimepicker';
```

The relevant part of the gemfile is also given below.

```
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.10'
gem 'bootstrap-sass',          '3.2.0.0'
gem 'sass-rails',              '5.0.2'
```

I have also set  `config.serve_static_files = true` in the production environment.

I am using Amazon's cloudfront to serve all my static assets. This might be causing a problem. Maybe I have not configured cloudfront properly to serve glyphicons. Not really sure why its not serving the glyphicons. Any help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your code is working locally - it's likely a problem with the way CloudFont is configured.

The boxes you see are showing because the fonts aren't being loaded - so your browser doesn't know what to display.

Check your settings in CloudFont - chances are you haven't whitelisted the production environment's hostname.

Comment: I am not sure where I whitelist the production enviornment's hostname. I clicked on setting and went through every tab but I can't find such option.

Comment: I followed the steps below and whitelisted as you mentioned. web interface for your Cloudfront “distribution,” and click “Distribution Settings,” then the “Behaviors” tab. Select the behavior (assuming you have only one) and click “Edit.”

For “Forward Headers,” change it from “None (Improves Caching)” to “Whitelist.” A “Whitelist Headers” section will appear. Add “Origin” to this list. This tells Cloudfront to take the “Origin” header into account when caching. This is the link I followed. http://www.holovaty.com/writing/cors-ie-cloudfront/

Comment: The link also mentioned to rename the font files after i was finished. Not sure what that means. the glyphicons have a specific class. If I rename it, it wouldn't be the same.

Comment: most of the time a good place to start is to check what is logged in your console